# I want to develop a windows application, after installation which should be able to do something whenever I use a hot key or a combination of keys

Tags: windows, copy, paste, hotkeys

I am developing an application that allows us to copy/ paste in the laptop/ phone and then paste in laptop/ phone. I created an android application that will copy the text over to the firebase database whenever I copy something on my phone. but for the second I have no idea how to create a windows app that can go the database and copy that text whenever I use a combination of keys let's say ctrl + alt + c. What the available technologies to achieve this?

Comment: Here is how you can make Webtequests with c# an .net. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient